# A closed form relation to compute the spectral norm of a 2x2 real matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms, discriminant, spectral-norm

I am reading [this](https://notendur.hi.is/mbh6/html/_downloads/Vector%20Calculus%20-%20Hubbard.pdf) book (page 215) and I found in the bottom of this page an interesting relation that I want to use. The relation is

$$||A||_2 = \sqrt{\frac{||A||_F^2 + \sqrt{||A||_F^4 - 4 (\mathrm{det}\:A)^2}}{2}},$$ where

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}$$ is a $2x2$ real matrix. The relation can be verified by using the definition of the spectral norm of $A$, i.e.,

$$||A||_2 = \sqrt{\lambda_\max (A^TA)}, $$ where $\lambda_\max (A^TA)$ is the maximum eigenvalue of $A^TA$. Solving

$$\mathrm{det}\: ( A^TA - \lambda \:I )=0$$ w.r.t. $\lambda$ we get the polynomial

$$p(\lambda) = \lambda^2 - ||A||_F^2\:\lambda + (\mathrm{det}\:A)^2=0$$ with discriminant

$$\Delta = ||A||_F^4 - 4(\mathrm{det} \:A)^2.$$ Thus, the maximum root of $p(\lambda)$ is

$$\lambda_\max(A^TA) = \frac{||A||_F^2 + \sqrt{||A||_F^4 - 4 (\mathrm{det}\:A)^2}}{2}$$ which is what the author in the book uses to get $||A||_2$, My question is, how do we know that $\Delta > 0$? Is there an inequality that gives an appropriate relation between $||A||_F$ and $\mathrm{det}\:A$ ? Could you please someone cast some light?

<sup>The author also has an exercise 2.8.8 where the square is missing in the determinant. Maybe it is a mistake.</sup>

Comment: $\|A\|_F^4=(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2)^2\ge4\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2=4(\det A)^2$, where the $\sigma_i$s are the singular values of $A$.

Comment: @user1551 thanks for the interest, I understand that $$||A||_F^4 = \sigma_1^4 + \sigma_2^4 + 2 \sigma_1^2 \sigma_2^2 \geq 2 \sigma_1^2 \sigma_2^2$$ but how we get the $4\sigma_1 \sigma_2$?

Comment: $(x+y)^2=(x-y)^2+4xy\ge4xy$ when $xy\ge0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $n \times n$ positive semidefinite matrix M we have

$$
\frac{\operatorname{tr}(M)}{n} \geq \operatorname{det}(M)^{1 / n}
$$

And $A^T A$ is a special case of positive semidefinite matrix for any matrix $A$.

Since $\left(\operatorname{tr} A^{T} A\right)^{1 / 2} = \|A\|_{F}$ we have using the inequality above,

$$\|A\|_{F}^{4} = \left(\operatorname{tr} A^{T} A\right)^2 \geq n^2 (\det({A^TA}))^\frac{2}{n} = n^2 \det({A})^\frac{4}{n} $$

The special case for n=2 is given by :

$$\|A\|_{F}^{4} \geq 4 \det(A)^2$$

which is exactly what you want.

Of course there is possibly a much easier way to derive this inequality in the case of a $2 \times 2$ matrix !